# How to get device context for for window, sub menus and context menus?

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot

I'm screen capturing application windows from their window handle (hwnd) and am getting their device context using `GetWindowDC` which I can use to capture the whole window, top level menu and scroll bars.

```
HDC hdcWindow = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
HDC hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow); // or hdcScreen
```

When I open a sub menu e.g. the File menu in the top left corner of Notepad, that menu is not captured. It doesn't seem to be included in the device context. Is there a way to get the device context for everything withing the application window?

Comment: You would need to get the display DC (GetDC(NULL)) then BitBlt the window rectangle

Comment: @AlexK. Technically, the popup menu can extend outside the window rectangle...

Comment: Hi Alex, That works quite well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The display abstraction presented by GDI is not aware of any of the magic performed by desktop composition - a window DC represents the area of a window on the display and if the window is not shown, or obscured by other windows, that area is clipped out and does not exist - you cannot blit to it using the window DC, and when reading it you will probably get blackness.

As such, to capture an area of the screen that including the content from multiple windows - you would need to use a screen, rather than window, DC.

Comment: How does this answer address the issue presented in the question?